# changing dates in a record

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Here the guy from the Baptism program again (Hopefully for the last time)

In the table Doopdata I stored all the days baptims take place in a certain church.

When de date of the baptisms changes on a certain date, the dates in de table Doopdata must be changed too from thatdate. (p.e. Baptism change from Sunday to Saturday). If people already asked for a baptism on a Sunday there is a problem. Therefor I check if baptisms are already asked on a Sunday. In this case I store this date in the table Problemen (Problems).

Later when I want to change all those dates I check if de date is in the table Problemen.
If so:

- the flag Problemen in the table Doopdata must by set on true.
- A new record must be added in the table Doopdata on the new date.
  if not:
  the date must be changed in the new date

I use this code

```
Do While Not rd.EOF
                'rd = recordset Doopdata
                'rp = recordset Problemen
                    zoeken = "Probdatum = " & MakeUSDate(rd!DoopDatum)'Doopdatum = date of Doopdata 
                    'MakeUSDate = function to make date American 
                    rp.FindFirst zoeken
                    If Not rp.NoMatch Then
                        oké = True
                    Else
                        oké = False
                    End If


                nieuwedatum = 0
                oudedatum = 0
                oudedatum = rd!DoopDatum 'is the date as it is before change
                nieuwedatum = DateAdd("d", verschil, oudedatum) 'Verschil = the difference in days. 
                'I made a function to calculate the difference and I know that is working fine

                If oké Then 'the date exists in Problemen 
                
                   'de vlag probleem wordt aangezet (problem flag is put on)
                   rd.Edit
                   rd!Probleem = True
                   rd.Update
                   
                   'er wordt een nieuw record aangemaakt op de nieuwe datum
                   'A new record is added
                   rd.AddNew
                   rd!DoopDatum = nieuwedatum
                   rd!LangeDatum = Format(nieuwedatum, "dddd d mmmm yyyy")
                   rd!KerkID = SID
                   rd!Aktief = True
                   
                   rd.Update

                Else 'the date doesn't exists in Problemen

                    'de datum wordt gewijzigd en alle doopmomenten worden op nul gezet
                    'all the dates from must be changed in the new dates                     
                        rd.Edit
                        rd!DoopDatum = nieuwedatum
                        rd!LangeDatum = Format(rd!DoopDatum, "dddd d mmmm yyyy")
                        rd!Annulatie = 0
                        rd!DAantal = 0
                        rd!Doop1 = 0
                        rd!Doop2 = 0
                        rd!Extra1 = 0
                        rd!Doop3 = 0
                        rd!Doop4 = 0
                        rd!Extra2 = 0
                        rd!Aktief = True
                        rd.Update
                End If
                rd.MoveNext
         Loop
```

I test the change of dates from a Sunday to a Friday and this from July first. I know there is a problem on August 20 (there is alreay an application for a Baptism on that Sunday).
So normally the record has to change the flag Problemen on true. I also add a new record on Friday the 18th.
I add a new record with the new date but the date I see on the new record is always Wednesday the 16th of August instead of Friday the 18th.
The Sunday I only changed the Flag Problemen as also change the date Doopdatum in the date of Friday althoug I didn't do it in the code
LangeDatum                  DoopDatum
woensdag 16 augustus 2023   16/08/2023
zondag 20 augustus 2023         18/08/2023

I already tried everything but nothing works
Is there a logical mistake in my code?
I searched for 2 days now altering my code but nothing works

I altered my code in different ways to find out where I made a mistake, but it doesn't help

Comment: Suggest you post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.